# Deletar varias linhas de um banco de dados

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, delete

Gostaria de deletar vários valores.
Por exemplo isso seria para deletar uma linha

```
  delete from paginasimagens where idPaginasImagens=121;
```

meus valores estão sequencialmente então um método que seja entre elementos serve;

Comment: você pode usar um `where coluna in (1,2,3)` ou `where coluna between 1 and 30`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Utilize o operador [`BETWEEN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) para obter o resultado desejado, utilizando o primeiro valor (que estará incluído na exclusão) e o último valor (que também será deletado):

```
DELETE FROM paginasimagens
 WHERE idPaginasImagens BETWEEN 121 AND 123;
```

> [`BETWEEN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)
>
> If `expr` is greater than or equal to min and `expr` is less than or equal to max, `BETWEEN` returns 1, otherwise it returns 0.

Em tradução livre:

> Se `expr` é maior ou igual ao mínimo e `expr` é menor ou igual ao máximo, `BETWEEN` retornará 1, senão retornará 0.

Answer (score 11):

Se você vai digitar manualmente os IDs:

```sql
delete from paginasimagens where idPaginasImagens in (121, 122, 123)
```

---

Se os IDs vêm de uma consulta:

```sql
delete from paginasimagens where idPaginasImagens in (SELECT idPaginasImagens FROM outraTabela)
```

---

Se você quer deletar uma sequência de IDs:

```sql
delete from paginasimagens where idPaginasImagens between 1 and 30
```

Comment: Na minha opinião, essa é a resposta mais adequada para a dúvida do usuário.

Answer (score 1):

Da pra deletar todos os dados da tabela também, com `TRUNCATE`:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE paginasimagens;
```

Comment: Inclusive se formatar o servidor geralmente apaga as linhas junto

Comment: @Sorack alternativa de hardware https://imgur.com/j0MqK4e

Comment: @Bacco justo hahaha

Answer (score -6):

Utiliza o *checkbox* em sua tabela `name="item[]"` no PHP cria um loop com `foreach`:

```
foreach($_POST['item'] as $item) {

  $sql("delete from paginasimagens WHERE id = '$item'");<br>
  $sql = $conexao->query($sql) or die($conexao->error);

}
```